# LSSVM hyperparameter tuning

Tags: hyperparameters

I want to set the initial value for LSSVM hyperparameter by using tunelssvm in matlab as follows:

```
dt = xlsread('USD_GBP.xlsx');
dt1 = dt(:,[1]);   %input
x = dt1(1:459,:);    %training
x1 = dt1(460:510,:);   %testing
dt2=dt(:,[2]);  %output
y=dt2(1:459,:);    %training
y1=dt2(460:510,:);  %testing
[gam, sig2, cost] = tunelssvm({x,y,'f',1,1,'RBF_kernel','preprocess'},'gridsearch', 'crossvalidatelssvm', {10,'mse'})
```

In the code, I want the starting value for gam and sig2 is 1. However, the result that i get for sig2 is 0.005... Can anyone help me on how can i set the starting value or making them in range?